# Persisting cumulated properties in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

What would be the best practice for saving a user profile in the database filled in different screens ?

I am cumulating properties in the state and would start saving only after filling the password.

1. Should I get the state in the action reducer ?
2. Pass the profile properties to the password screen and have it as parameter in the action reducer ?

Comment: Are you trying to build some sort of screens that the user works through and then at the end you send all that information to a server to create a user? Basically a user onboarding flow?

Comment: You can save properties in state until final step / screen for your registration process, then on the final screen you should link all stored state properties and dispatch to API request function.

Comment: @nevans91 yes, just I will not only save at the end, after a specific step the user would be created and he can continue later ;)

Comment: @JigarShah so what you say is I should pass the state to the screen ? And then it would be in param of the action creator ?

Comment: I have managed by adding state for other properties and once I get password' value, I have dispatched to my API method.